# How to test modal is rendering or not?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, react-hooks, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component consisting of a button and when the user clicks the button modal is shown but rendered outside the root div using the portal. How to test whether the modal is rendering or not using jest and RTL?

File to test

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Modal from '../Modal';
export const MyComponent = () => {
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    return (
        <>
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    setIsOpen(true);
                }}
            >
                Open Modal
            </button>
            <Modal
                isOpen={isOpen}
                toggeleVisibility={() => {
                    setIsOpen(false);
                }}
                content={<div>Modal content</div>}
            />
        </>
    );
};
```

Modal.tsx

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';
const Modal = ({ isOpen, toggeleVisibility, content }: any) => {
    const modalRenderDiv = document.querySelector('#modal-div');
    const el = useRef(document.createElement('div'));
    useEffect(() => {
        const current = el.current;
        modalRenderDiv.appendChild(current);
        return () => void modalRenderDiv.removeChild(current);
    }, []);
    return isOpen ? createPortal({ content }, el.current) : null;
};
export default Modal;
```

MyComponent.test.tsx

```
import { render, fireEvent, act } from '@testing-library/react';
import configureStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { MyComponent } from '../MyComponent';

const initialState = {};
const mockStore = configureStore();
const store = mockStore(initialState);
function renderComp() {
    return render(
        <Provider store={store}>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <MyComponent />
            </BrowserRouter>
        </Provider>
    );
}

test('render', async () => {
    let comp: any;
    await act(async () => {
        comp = renderComponent();
    });
    const { getByRole } = comp;
    const getButton = getByRole('button');
    fireEvent.click(getButton);
});
```

HTML structure of file is like

```
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id="modal-div"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

`createPortal` accepts a React Node as its first parameter, NOT a JS plain object. See below function signature:

```
export function createPortal(children: ReactNode, container: Element, key?: null | string): ReactPortal;
```

Firstly, set up the HTML template for RTL like the real one. Our test environment is JSDOM, so we can use DOM API to create a `$root` HTML div element and pass it to [container](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/api#container) option of the `render` function. Set up the `modal` container div element too.

E.g.

`MyComponent.tsx`:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import Modal from './Modal';

export const MyComponent = () => {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Open Modal</button>
      <Modal isOpen={isOpen} toggeleVisibility={() => setIsOpen(false)} content={<div>Modal content</div>} />
    </>
  );
};
```

`Modal.tsx`:

```
import { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { createPortal } from 'react-dom';

const Modal = ({ isOpen, toggeleVisibility, content }) => {
  const el = useRef(document.createElement('div'));
  useEffect(() => {
    const modalRenderDiv = document.querySelector('#modal-div');
    const current = el.current;
    modalRenderDiv?.appendChild(current);
    return () => void modalRenderDiv?.removeChild(current);
  }, []);

  return isOpen ? createPortal(content, el.current) : null;
};

export default Modal;
```

`MyComponent.test.tsx`:

```
import { fireEvent, render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import React from 'react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';
import { MyComponent } from './MyComponent';

describe('73605370', () => {
  let $root: HTMLDivElement;
  let $modalContainer: HTMLDivElement;
  beforeEach(() => {
    $root = document.createElement('div');
    $root.id = 'root';
    $modalContainer = document.createElement('div');
    $modalContainer.id = 'modal-div';
    document.body.appendChild($root);
    document.body.appendChild($modalContainer);
  });
  afterEach(() => {
    document.body.removeChild($root);
    document.body.removeChild($modalContainer);
  });
  test('should pass', async () => {
    render(<MyComponent />, { container: $root });
    const $button = screen.getByText(/open modal/i);
    expect(screen.queryByText(/modal content/i)).not.toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.click($button);
    expect(screen.queryByText(/modal content/i)).toBeInTheDocument();
  });
});
```

Test result:

```bash
 PASS  stackoverflow/73605370/MyComponent.test.tsx (11.626 s)
  73605370
    ✓ should pass (39 ms)

-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File             | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files        |      95 |       80 |   83.33 |   94.44 |                   
 Modal.tsx       |     100 |       80 |     100 |     100 | 9-10              
 MyComponent.tsx |    87.5 |      100 |   66.67 |   85.71 | 9                 
-----------------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.287 s
```

package versions:

```json
"react": "^16.14.0",
"react-dom": "^16.14.0",
"@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
"jest": "^26.6.3",
```

Comment: "_Firstly, set up the HTML template for RTL like the real one._" That common-sensical kick in the pants there was exactly what I needed to figure out my issue. 